How to Configure Multiple Datasources in Spring Modulith?
Is there a way to set up multiple datasources (all mysql) in a Spring Boot application using Spring Modulith, where each module has a different database and schema, without manually defining beans like HikariDataSource, LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, and PlatformTransactionManager for each module? Looking for a more automated and less verbose approach.
I'm doing it like this now:
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "auth")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "authEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "authTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {
                "auth.repository"
        }
)
@EntityScan(basePackages = "common.model.entity")
class AuthDataSourceConfig {

    public static final String 
JPA_REPOSITORIES_PACKAGE 
= "auth.repository";
    public static final String 
JPA_ENTITIES_PACKAGE 
= "common.model.entity";

    @Bean(name = "authDataSource")
    public HikariDataSource authDataSource(AuthDataSourceProperties authDataSourceProperties) {
        return new HikariDataSource(authDataSourceProperties);
    }

    @Bean(name = "authEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean authEntityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("authDataSource") HikariDataSource authDataSource,
            JpaProperties jpaProperties,
            ObjectProvider<PersistenceUnitManager> persistenceUnitManager) {

        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder = new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(
                new org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(),
                jpaProperties.getProperties(),
                persistenceUnitManager.getIfAvailable()
        );

        return builder
                .dataSource(authDataSource)
                .packages("common.model.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("authDataSource")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "authTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager authTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("authEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory authEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(authEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}

properties
  datasource-auth:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql

  another-auth:
...


No there isn't. Using Spring Modulith doesn't magically add features to Spring Boot. So if you need multiple datasources, entitymanagers etc. you still will need to define them manually. You could provide a factory yourself to make this easier (especially if you follow the same approach for each one), which would make things a bit easier.
